# strToInt function convert list of characters to integer in C

Tags: c, string, character

In C, I need a function that takes an alphanumerical list characters from `0-9` and converts it to an integer.

Code:

```
int strToInt(char string[])
{
    int i, intValue, result = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i] > '0' && string[i] <= '9'; ++i)
    {
        intValue = string[i] - '0';
        result = ???
    }
    return result;
}
```

What do I put in the ??? to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
result = result * 10 + intValue;
```

Also:

```
string[i] > '0'
```

in the `for` loop seems nasty - numbers can contain the digit 0, right? You may want to use

```
string[i] >= '0'
```

instead, or even better, without reinventing the wheel:

```
#include <ctype.h>

for (i = 0; isdigit(string[i]); ++i)
```

Comment: Might be also worth pointing out that the strict comparison in `string[i] > '0'` is probably a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the answer was realy helpfull!

Comment: @poseidon11 You can express your appreciation by accepting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed is like reinventing the wheel but is more like learning the structure not make it work with the best eficient way :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, your string is in decimal, base 10, and each digit in the string represents a position in a base 10 system. I.e. So you'd want to do

```
 result = result * 10 + intValue;
```

Remember that '0' is also a digit, so you don't want to omit that one, Use `string[i] >= '0'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about base `10`, you should probably include `0` also as a digit and hence

```
string[i] >= '0'
```

in your `for` loop. and usual place value calculation

```
result = result*10 + intValue;
```